# Game Center turn based game

Tags: swift, cocoa-touch, ios8

I have made a word game. I works well and I can start a game center game. But I have a problem. I want both of the users to see the same things on the screen. Like a checkers or a chess game.

```
    var imageLinksArray = [String]()
    var enArray = [String]()
    var arrayNumber:Int = 0


    let localFilePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("JSON",ofType:"json")
    var readError:NSError?
    if let dataLocal = NSData(contentsOfFile:localFilePath!, options:NSDataReadingOptions.DataReadingUncached, error:&readError) {
        let stringData = NSString(data: dataLocal, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        let json = JSON(data: dataLocal)



        for result in json["words"].arrayValue {

            let en = result["en"].stringValue

            enArray.append(en)

        }

        var randomArrayNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(enArray.count)))
        arrayNumber = Int(randomArrayNumber)

    }
```

This is how I get the word from the JSON file. I want the both players to see same word. Can somebody please explain the logic to me?

Answer (score 0):

You will need some kind of server software to keep the game session state. Game Center offer a couple of solutions for this, and other options could be to build your own server or roll some kind of peer-to-peer.

This is a large field and I would recommend some research and some reading on the topic.

Comment: What does Game Center offer exactly? I do not think I need a separate server to make a turn based game. I think Game Center can handle it. Am I wrong?

Comment: I read the documentation about turn based games. This link does not really help. I need someone to explain the code structure and the logic of turn based games. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are creating the data for the game (a word in this case) and you want to persist this data as the match progresses. If so, you will need to store your word in the matchData field of the Match object. You do this by converting your word (and other relevant data) to NSData and storing in matchData. Not sure if this is your question. I need more information.